# error NETSDK1004 Assets file project.assets.json not found and error MSB4036 The "GetReferenceNearestTargetFrameworkTask" task was not found

Tags: c#, .net-core, msbuild, rider

I worked on this computer on the same dotnet projects for 2-3 months and only after installing JetBrains Rider I got a surprise. Running `dotnet restore` did not output anything and running `dotnet build`, `dotnet watch build` or anything like that outputted an error saying this:

```
error NETSDK1004: Assets file project.assets.json not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file.
```

The worst thing was that `dotnet build` failed with an error, but `msbuild` ran on the same project successfully built the project (figuring out to try `msbuild` took quite some time too). Which seems bonkers and does not explain anything.

After fiddling around by reinstalling all 10 or so .NET Core SDK versions that were accumulated, nothing changed. But I think after uninstalling Rider I started getting another error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1655,5): error MSB4036: The "GetReferenceNearestTargetFrameworkTask" task was not found. Check the following: 1.) The name of the task in the project file is the same as the name of the task class. 2.) The task class is "public" and implements the Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask interface. 3.) The task is correctly declared with <UsingTask> in the project file, or in the *.tasks files located in the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin" directory.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr:
Removed this environment variable:

```
MSBUILD_EXE_PATH
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe
```

And all `dotnet` CLI commands started working again.
How did it get there - I don't know, could have been Rider who added it there. But I had two CMD windows open and until you restart the CMD it has the same environment variables.

The one with `MSBUILD_EXE_PATH` set had the error and the one without it did not and worked fine.

I hope this helps someone to not waste a day and a half of work by looking everywhere and not understanding what's happening.

Comment: I'm getting this same error but I don't have a MSBUILD_EXE_PATH environmental variable at all.